# Create multiple API Gateway methods within a given path and iterate the same for other paths as well

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_method" "method" {
  for_each                  = toset(["OPTIONS", "GET"])   
  rest_api_id               = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.apigw.id
  resource_id              = aws_api_gateway_resource.auditlog.id
  http_method               = each.key
  authorization             = var.authorizations # "NONE"
  request_parameters        = var.request_parameters # {}
  request_models            = var.request_models
}
```

Here, the `resourceid` will be varied based on the different resources that are created in interation. Hence, I would like to create methods `GET` and `OPTIONS` for each `resource_id`. *Another challenge that I am facing is that the `resource_id` has something like `{id}` for couple of paths. Not sure how to point it to a different resource each time.

I tried something the below code but it did not work for me

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_method" "method" {
  
  for_each                  = toset(["OPTIONS", "GET"])   
  rest_api_id               = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.apigw.id
  #resource_id              = aws_api_gateway_resource.auditlog.id
  http_method               = each.key#var.http_methods
  authorization             = "NONE"
  request_parameters        = {}
  request_models            = var.request_models  
  
  dynamic "resource_id" {
    for_each                = local.apigw_resource_id
    content {
        resource_id               = each.value.id
        
    }
  }
}
```

```
locals {
  apigw_resource_id = {
    "auditlog" = {
        id                      = "aws_api_gateway_resource.auditlog.id"
    },
    "info" = {
        id                      = "aws_api_gateway_resource.info.id"
    },
    "{id}" = {
        id                      = "aws_api_gateway_resource.{id}.id"
    }
  }
}
```

The `{id}` are multiple for multiple resource, hence I am not sure how exactly it will identify that it needs to go to say: `/this/info/{id}` for the first time and then `/this/entities/{id}` for the second time.

[The error I get when performing the above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0aqVC.png)

Comment: So what is the question here? Does this code work? Are there any errors?

Comment: No, I am confused as I am not sure as to how I need to proceed in order to provide the next path's id. Since, both the paths have the path_part as {id} - not sure as to how do I give it? Also, if there is any alternative option to lessen this method because I need to create 99 methods in each API

Comment: Additionally, the `resource_id` argument is required, so it cannot be used with `dynamic`. If you need to create that many, maybe you can take a look at how to create them using OpenAPI spec instead of terraform.

Comment: Can you please share any links to refer?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-import-api.html

Comment: @MarkoE, Thanks for the inputs but I would like to try in terraform and hence I did it but ended up facing an issue saying "Unsupported block type" for using dynamic within the Method resource. I have attached the image as well fyr. Pls let me know if there is any workaround?

Comment: You can as well do that in terraform, there are examples in the provider documentation on how to do it: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/api_gateway_rest_api#openapi-specification.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers, I am using the OpenAPI spec now but facing another issue - it is throwing 403 while deploying, not sure if I have to give any roles/policies in order to deploy the API gateways. The link for the issue is here -> https://stackoverflow.com/q/75969883/21536709