# Getting error 403 while deploying the API Gateway using terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am deploying the API Gateway resource using the OpenAPI specs. The apply step throws as error with status code 403 while deploying. I am unable to figure out what roles/policies I need to use create in order to have the API Gateway deployed.

Below is the error:

```
Error: Error creating API Gateway: AccessDeniedException: 
│   status code: 403, request id: 52a64b5c-709e-4214-8789-510ace031176
│ 
│   with module.apigw["digitalts-devtest-lab-backend"].aws_api_gateway_rest_api.restapi,
│   on .terraform/modules/apigw/main.tf line 1, in resource "aws_api_gateway_rest_api" "restapi":
│    1: resource "aws_api_gateway_rest_api" "restapi" {


Error: Error creating API Gateway: AccessDeniedException: 
│   status code: 403, request id: bf46f9aa-3521-4fa5-893c-c3af227f8f3b
│ 
│   with module.apigw["digitalts-devtest-beta-backend"].aws_api_gateway_rest_api.restapi,
│   on .terraform/modules/apigw/main.tf line 1, in resource "aws_api_gateway_rest_api" "restapi":
│    1: resource "aws_api_gateway_rest_api" "restapi" {
```

Below is what I tried:

Module code:

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_rest_api" "restapi" {
  body = jsonencode({
    openapi = "3.0.1"
    info = {
      title   = "DTS API GATEWAY"
      version = "1.0"
    }
    paths = {
        "/auditlog" = {
            "get" = {
                x-amazon-apigateway-integration = {
                    httpMethod           = "GET"
                    payloadFormatVersion = "1.0"
                    type                 = "LAMBDA_PROXY"
                    uri                  = var.lambda_uri_getAuditLog
                }
                x-amazon-apigateway-auth = {
                    type: "NONE"
                }
            },
            "options" = {
                x-amazon-apigateway-integration = {
                    httpMethod      = "OPTIONS"
                    payloadFormatVersion = "1.0"
                    type                 = "MOCK"
                    uri                  = ""
                    "requestTemplates" : {
                        "application/json" : {
                            "statusCode" : "200"
                        }
                    }
                    "response" : {
                        "statusCode"            : "200"
                        "responseTemplates"     : {
                            "application/json"  : {}
                        "responseParameters"    : {
                            "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": "true",
                            "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "'*'",
                            "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "'*'",
                            "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin": ""
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                x-amazon-apigateway-auth = {
                    type: "NONE"
                }
                "response" : {
                    "statusCode"            : "200"
                    "responseParameters"    : {
                        "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": "",
                        "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "",
                        "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "",
                        "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin": ""
                    }  
                }
            }
        }
        "/dependencytable" = {
            "post" = {
                x-amazon-apigateway-integration = {
                    httpMethod           = "POST"
                    payloadFormatVersion = "1.0"
                    type                 = "LAMBDA_PROXY"
                    uri                  = var.lambda_uri_postDependencyTable
                }
                x-amazon-apigateway-auth = {
                    type: "NONE"
                }
            },
            "options" = {
                x-amazon-apigateway-integration = {
                    httpMethod      = "OPTIONS"
                    payloadFormatVersion = "1.0"
                    type                 = "MOCK"
                    uri                  = ""
                    "requestTemplates" : {
                        "application/json" : {
                            "statusCode" : "200"
                        }
                    }
                    "response" : {
                        "statusCode"            : "200"
                        "responseTemplates"     : {
                            "application/json"  : {}
                        "responseParameters"    : {
                            "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": "true",
                            "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "'*'",
                            "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "'*'",
                            "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin": ""
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                x-amazon-apigateway-auth = {
                    type: "NONE"
                }
                "response" : {
                    "statusCode"            : "200"
                    "responseParameters"    : {
                        "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": "",
                        "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "",
                        "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "",
                        "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin": ""
                    }  
                }
            }
        },
        "/dts/info" = {
            "get" = {
                x-amazon-apigateway-integration = {
                    httpMethod           = "GET"
                    payloadFormatVersion = "1.0"
                    type                 = "LAMBDA_PROXY"
                    uri                  = var.lambda_uri_getDtsInfo
                }
                x-amazon-apigateway-auth = {
                    type: "NONE"
                }
            },
            "options" = {
                x-amazon-apigateway-integration = {
                    httpMethod      = "OPTIONS"
                    payloadFormatVersion = "1.0"
                    type                 = "MOCK"
                    uri                  = ""
                    "requestTemplates" : {
                        "application/json" : {
                            "statusCode" : "200"
                        }
                    }
                    "response" : {
                        "statusCode"            : "200"
                        "responseTemplates"     : {
                            "application/json"  : {}
                        "responseParameters"    : {
                            "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": "true",
                            "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "'*'",
                            "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "'*'",
                            "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin": ""
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                x-amazon-apigateway-auth = {
                    type: "NONE"
                }
                "response" : {
                    "statusCode"            : "200"
                    "responseParameters"    : {
                        "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": "",
                        "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "",
                        "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "",
                        "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin": ""
                    }  
                }
            }
        },
        "/entities/{entityId}/subtract/{incrementId}" = {
            "delete" = {
                x-amazon-apigateway-integration = {
                    httpMethod           = "DELETE"
                    payloadFormatVersion = "1.0"
                    type                 = "LAMBDA_PROXY"
                    uri                  = var.lambda_uri_incrementId
                }
                x-amazon-apigateway-auth = {
                    type: "NONE"
                }
                "parameters": [
                    {
                    "in" : "query"
                    "name": "entityId"
                    "schema": {
                        "type": "string"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                    "in" : "query"
                    "name": "incrementId"
                    "schema": {
                        "type": "string"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            "post" = {
                x-amazon-apigateway-integration = {
                    httpMethod           = "POST"
                    payloadFormatVersion = "1.0"
                    type                 = "LAMBDA_PROXY"
                    uri                  = var.lambda_uri_incrementId
                }
                x-amazon-apigateway-auth = {
                    type: "NONE"
                }
                "parameters": [
                    {
                    "in" : "query"
                    "name": "entityId"
                    "schema": {
                        "type": "string"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                    "in" : "query"
                    "name": "incrementId"
                    "schema": {
                        "type": "string"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            "options" = {
                x-amazon-apigateway-integration = {
                    httpMethod      = "OPTIONS"
                    payloadFormatVersion = "1.0"
                    type                 = "MOCK"
                    uri                  = ""
                    "requestTemplates" : {
                        "application/json" : {
                            "statusCode" : "200"
                        }
                    }
                    "response" : {
                        "statusCode"            : "200"
                        "responseTemplates"     : {
                            "application/json"  : {}
                        "responseParameters"    : {
                            "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": "true",
                            "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "'*'",
                            "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "'*'",
                            "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin": ""
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                x-amazon-apigateway-auth = {
                    type: "NONE"
                }
                "response" : {
                    "statusCode"            : "200"
                    "responseParameters"    : {
                        "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": "",
                        "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "",
                        "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "",
                        "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin": ""
                    }  
                }
            }
        }
    }
    })

  name = var.api_gateway_name

  endpoint_configuration {
    types = var.endpoint_configuration
  }
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_deployment" "deployment" {
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.restapi.id

  triggers = {
    redeployment = sha1(jsonencode(aws_api_gateway_rest_api.restapi.body))
  }

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
}
```

My deployment :

```
module "apigw" {
  source = "../api-gateway-new/aws"
  version = "0.0.6"

  for_each  = local.api_gateway

  api_gateway_name  = each.value.api_gateway_name
  lambda_uri_getAuditLog = var.lambda_uri_getAuditLog
  lambda_uri_postDependencyTable  = var.lambda_uri_postDependencyTable
  lambda_uri_getDtsInfo = var.lambda_uri_getDtsInfo
  lambda_uri_incrementId  = var.lambda_uri_incrementId
  endpoint_configuration  = var.endpoint_configuration


}
```

Locals:

```
locals {
    api_gateway = {
    "digitalts-devtest-beta-backend" = {
      api_gateway_name                = var.api_gateway_name_beta
      #lambda_uri_getAuditLog          = var.lambda_uri_getAuditLog

    },
    "digitalts-devtest-lab-backend" = {
      api_gateway_name                = var.api_gateway_name_lab
      #uri                             = var.uri_lab

    }
}
}
```

Comment: You should look in cloudtrail to find these API requests and you should see for what reason / permissions the request was rejected for.

Comment: I havent set up the cloudtrail but will it give me the logs before the APIs are deployed? I mean, my case is I am getting the above error at the time of creating the API gateway - will that be captured under cloudtrail?

Comment: Yes cloudtrail is available by default and at no charge. It should record all your api events to AWS and log them with the result and in the case of failures the error

Comment: I dont find anything related to the above errors in cloudtrail, is there any other way to understand the reason behind the above error?

Comment: you can set the variable `TF_LOG=debug` to increase the terraform log but it likley wont give you any more detail as it seems AWS isnt sending back any more. However you could take the request and get its ID and trace that in cloudtrail

Comment: Also how are you searching cloud trail?

Comment: Yes, I am searching by the request ID given in the error

Comment: Cloudwatch doesnt have an attribute for request ID searchable in the console. So you wont find anything for that. You would be better searching as the terraform user thats submitting the requests. and downloading the events or searching by resource type or something

Comment: @Shafeeq I think Lambda proxy integration has to be of type "POST".

Comment: @MarkoE - Thanks! I will try it out, facing couple other issues - once done, will try to update the post with the results.

Comment: @ChrisDoyle - Thanks for your inputs, was able to figure out the error details in the cloudtrail & was able to fix it.

Comment: Thats great news. Cloudtrail can be useful once you get the hang of it and get a feel fro what your looking for. I wish more of these errors were just transparent and returned and shown in terraform